# How do I improve performance on an ATI Radeon 9550?

Tags: drivers, ati, display, radeon

I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu (32-bit) and I didn't find a solution to make my video card work fine.

I mean that my graphic card has poor performance on watching videos.
I've tried a lot of tutorials but with no succes.
Also some codecs, plugins could help me.

Comment: define "work fine", what is your problem, it's impossible to help you without a proper question

Comment: for example, when I'm watching videos on Youtube it moves slow and also  if I watch in fullscreen  it moves like crap.

Comment: What driver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Updating to the latest driver version is the first step. After that just remove intensive options from the Ati control panel like AA, Vertical Sync and any other that are heavy of the FPS. Here is a link to the latest driver version http://linux.softpedia.com/progChangelog/ATI-Radeon-Linux-Display-Drivers-Changelog-6719.html

It is very tough to find the changelog since the AMD/Ati webpage does not have a easy driver download for Linux and there is no direct link to the changelog for the Linux version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the fglrx driver and are using Ubuntu3D, make sure you have Sync To VBlank option unchecked in CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM) under OpenGL section. Worked for me.